# sql scripting to fetch only few rows that matches given condition

Tags: sql-server, join

I have table.

```
id       dept         Person
1        ece            p1
2        ece            p1
3        ece            null
4        ece            null
6        eee            null
5        eee            p2
6        Civil          P3
7        Civil          P4
8        Civil          null
```

Replace null values with their respective person values based on department.In this case We have to ignore Civil as Civil as 2 person P3 and P4. We need to care only dept that have unique persons that is (ece and eee).

1 ) **Output should be like**

```
id       dept         Person
1        ece            p1
2        ece            p1
**3        ece            p1
4        ece            p1**
**6        eee            p2**
5        eee            p2
6        Civil          P3
7        Civil          P4
```

I have question how to fetch only rows,  whose dept has more than distinct person.

2)   **id**  **dept**  **Person**

```
4        Civil          P3
5        Civil          P4
```

Q3)

```
id      dept         Person       Rating
1       ece            p1           R1  
2**     ece            p2           Null**     
6       eee            P6           R1             
5**     eee            p2           Null**
6       Civil          P7           Null
7       Civil          P3           Null 
8       Civil          P8           R5
9       Mech           p7           R2
10      Mech           P3           Null
```

For Q3). I need only rows whose person's Ratings are null and their respective persons in different team, ratings are same. Because P2 is in different teams ece and eee their respective person's ratings is same that is **R1**

**Output for Q3**

```
id      dept         Person       Rating
2       ece            p2           Null  
5       eee            p2           Null
```

It should not contain following rows, because P3 is in both Civil and Mech but person's ratings are different **that is R5 and R2**

Output **should not include** these below records.
    id      dept         Person       Rating
    7       Civil          P3           Null 
    10      Mech           P3           Null

Comment: I have one more question.

Comment: As for Q3: Person p2 does not have a rating of R1. Why is p3 not returned in the result?

Comment: Q3).  P2 does not have rating. But I need them in output because, P2 is in Dept ece and eee, In ece we have P1 with rating R1, and in eee we have P6 with R1 both with same ratings that is why I  need P2 in output.   I dont need P3 in output because P3 is in Civil and Mech, Civil has P8 with R5 and Mech has P7 with R2 both are Different ratings and hence  I dont need P3 in Output.

Comment: Q3         [Note: Even though P1 does not have  Ratings' s I need them in output So that I can (in near future not needed now) assign the Rating R1 because eee(p6) ece(p1) has Rating R1. ]

Comment: Ok, I see. So  the "respective person's ratings" are the non-null-ratings of the other persons in the same dept?

Comment: @ Kais. Yes correct.

Comment: Should the query return a person that is in 2 teams, without "respective persons" and that has a null-rating in just one of the two teams? Should that person be returned at least with the dept where it has a null-rating?

Comment: @Kais.  the query Should return a person that is in 2 or more  teams, without "respective persons" and that has a null-rating in 2 or more teams.

Comment: Please see my answer on this.

Comment: @Kais. I have posted new questions. Could you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52635177/7864891

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:**

You can use a subquery that finds all depts with more than one distinct person and then find all records where the dept is in that list:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ihavetable
WHERE dept IN (
  SELECT dept 
  FROM Ihavetable 
  GROUP BY dept
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Person) > 1
  );
```

**Q2:**

To return all records but for depts with exactly one distinct Person replace the NULL values in the Person column with exactly that unique Person, you could use something like this:

```
WITH
    calculation (dept, num, pMax) AS (
        SELECT dept, COUNT(DISTINCT Person), MAX(Person)
        FROM Ihavetable
        GROUP BY dept
    )
SELECT t.id, t.dept,
    CASE c.num 
        WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(t.Person, c.pMax)
        ELSE t.person
    END AS Person
FROM Ihavetable t
  LEFT JOIN calculation c ON t.dept = c.dept
```

If you don't want to see the NULL values that are not replaceable, add this WHERE clause in the end:

```
WHERE c.num = 1 OR t.Person IS NOT NULL;
```

**Q3:**

This query will return all persons that have a null-rating in at least 2 teams and where all his "respective persons" (colleagues) in these teams that have a non-null-rating have the same non-null-rating (where the person itself can be its own colleague having a non-null-rating in a third team):

```
WITH
    calculation AS (
        SELECT t1.Person
        FROM Ihavetable t1
            INNER JOIN Ihavetable t2 ON t1.dept = t2.dept
        WHERE t1.Rating IS NULL
        GROUP BY t1.Person
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Rating) = 1
           AND COUNT(DISTINCT t2.dept) >= 2
    )
SELECT id, dept, Person, Rating
FROM Ihavetable
WHERE Rating IS NULL
  AND Person IN (SELECT Person FROM calculation);
```

Comment: Thank you Kais for your answer. But it is treating null also as one Distinct value. But I tried                                                                                                         GROUP BY dept
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Person) > 1 && Person Is not Null );.     But Its not working

Comment: @vishal No, `COUNT` doesn't count NULL values. If your result contains NULL values, that's ok, then the resulting depts have records where the `Person` is NULL, but they also have at least 2 records with 2 different non-NULL persons.

Comment: I got it. Thank you Kais for your help.

Comment: @vishal You are welcome. By the way: Kais is my lastname, and you (and all others) are allowed to call me Wolfgang. :-)

Comment: SELECT *
FROM Ihavetable
WHERE dept IN (
  SELECT dept 
  FROM Ihavetable 
  GROUP BY dept
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Person) = 1
  );        As we know that it fetches distinct persons p1 along with the nulls.    Now How do I set the nulls with the value P1.

Comment: @vishal What are you trying to achieve? Do you now want to retrieve "the other" depts (those that do **not** have at least 2 distinct persons)? If so, use `<= 1`.

Comment: Yes I used <=1. I get other depts which do not have at least 2 distinct persons and also I get the dept which have null values. Now I would like to set  Nulls to some value like P1.    If that dept has P1 set all other null values to P1, If any other department has P2 and null values, then set all other null values to P2.

Comment: @vishal Ok, I see. And what about the Null values in depts that do not have exactly one person (either only Nulls or Nulls and more than one person)?

Comment: Null values in dept that exactly have one person. we have to assign values of person in place of null

Comment: @vishal Just added an example to my answer.

Comment: @Kais.Thank you very much for helping me. I will go through the code.

Comment: @Kais. Just added Q3 which is a new scenario.  If possible could you please provide answer for Q3.

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Rating) = 1` checks that the colleagues all have the same non-null-rating, `AND COUNT(DISTINCT t2.dept) >= 2` makes sure that the number of departments where the person has null-ratings is at least 2 (I read that requirement in your last reply on my question on your post).

Comment: Got it. Thank you Kais.

Comment: @Kais. Thank you for your help. It would be really great if you could let me know "when to use which instance".   I am not getting any result when I use T1 instance instead of T2 instance, for this query. In what scenario should we use self join.                                                 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Rating) = 1
            AND COUNT(DISTINCT t2.dept) >= 2.

Comment: Since T1 holds the person that I'm interested in (I used that one to group on), T2 holds the colleagues from his departments (the ones who's distinct ratings are counted). For counting the distinct departments, it in fact doesn't matter whether to use T1 or T2, because both tables are "INNER JOINED" by the `dept` field (which is counted), so on every match, the values from both sides are the same. The self join is needed to find the "respective persons" for a person, because these are persons, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `COUNT` with window function, get the number by `dept` column the get `cnt > 1` data.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY dept) cnt
   FROM T
)t1
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not exactly what I need. Your solution returns both ECE and Civil.  I need only Civil rows as it has two different Persons P3,P4