# Fetch rows based on their values in a group in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
id      dept         Person       Rating
-------------------------------------------
1       ece            p1           R1  
2       ece            p2           t1
3       eee            P3           R2             
4       eee            p4           M
5       Civil          P5           R2
6       Civil          P6           t2
7       Civil          P7           t2
8       Mech           p8           R2
9       Mech           P9           Null
10      IT             P10          R2J
11      IT             P11          T2
12      IT             P12          T2
```

I would like to fetch all the dept  rows  whose ratings are null in a dept ,or  whose ratings are M in a dept, or whose " t" ratings  are different to that of "P" in a dept.

**Desired output:**

```
3       eee            P3           R2             
4       eee            p4           M
8       Mech           p8           R2
9       Mech           P9           Null
10      IT             P10          R2J
11      IT             P11          T2
12      IT             P12          T2
```

**Note 1:** "t" ratings  are different to that of "R" in a dept, it means if a person rating in a dept is R2 then other persons in dept ratings is  T1. **Example** dept IT.

**Note 2:** "t" ratings  are same to that of "R" in a dept, it means if a person rating in a dept is R1 then other persons in dept ratings is  T1. **Example** dept **ECE**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will Rating always be of the format "<Alphabet><Number>" when it is either an R or T?

Comment: @Sravana. Yes. it is

Comment: Hi, please try to add a query or at least table name's for us to provide you some help.

Comment: @Sravana. Thank you for your help. but some times some of the rating values are R1s and T2 in that way so how do I cope up  with this. Here The condition should check 1 and 2.             it should be like 1<>2.  How do I extract 1 from R1s and 2 from T2?                 Some times there are also T2s and all

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right you can use an `EXISTS` in another `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM elbat t2
                            WHERE t2.dept = t1.dept
                                  AND (t2.rating IS NULL
                                        OR t2.rating = 'M'
                                         OR t2.rating LIKE 'T%'
                                            AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                               FROM elbat t3
                                                               WHERE t3.dept = t2.dept
                                                                     AND t3.rating LIKE 'R%'
                                                                     AND right(t2.rating, len(t2.rating) - 1) <> right(t3.rating, len(t3.rating) - 1))));
```

Answer (score 0):

(from another question of yours I doubt you are understanding the replies, anyway I hope you at least try)

```
Select * from myTable t1
where exists (
select * from myTable t2 
where t1.dept = t2.dept AND
  (t2.rating = 'M' or 
   t2.rating is null or 
   right(t1.Rating,1) <> right(t2.Rating,1))
);
```

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ec051ddea383c3785a3186cfe9345d5f)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union and then do a self-join on dept to obtain your results

```
 SELECT id, dept, Person, Rating FROM Test 
 WHERE Rating IS NULL OR Rating = 'M'
 UNION
 SELECT t1.id, t1.dept, t1.Person, t1.Rating 
 FROM Test t1 
 INNER JOIN Test t2 ON
 t1.dept = t2.dept 
 WHERE
 RIGHT(ISNULL(t1.Rating,0),1) <> RIGHT(ISNULL(t2.Rating,0),1)
```

Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ffb11/17)

Comment: In order to make it possible. I am using Union all. Also I go to know that I could use RIGHT(t.Rating, LEN(t.Rating)-1) in this way as well. Thank you All

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, for a record to be returned, the rating must be `M` or `NULL` or it must start with `R` or `T`. The starting letters `R` and `T` for ratings are treated as if they were equal, and if that condition meets, at least one other person in that dept must have a different rating (either not starting with `R` or `T` or with a different R-T-rating). If this is correct, the following query will return the desired result:

```
SELECT id, dept, Person, Rating
FROM Ihavetable t
WHERE Rating IS NULL 
   OR Rating = 'M'
   OR Rating LIKE '[RT]_%'
   AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Ihavetable
        WHERE dept = t.dept
          AND ISNULL(Rating, '') NOT LIKE '[RT]' + RIGHT(t.Rating, LEN(t.Rating)-1)
    );
```

Comment: @Kais. Thank you :) . If I got it right, for a record to be returned, the rating must be M or NULL or it must start with R or T. The starting letters R and T for ratings are treated as if they were equal.  Till this it is correct. I need  if a dept consists R1 and T1 I do not need those rows. But if a dept consists of R1 and T2 then I need those rows.

Comment: Yes, und you seem to also need R1/T1 together with M or NULL or any other Tx/Rx with x other than 1. That's what I thought that I have implemented.

Comment: I only seem to need  M or NULL or any other Tx/Ry, where x!=y.